# can't deploy process in activiti after integrating with LDAP

Tags: openldap, activiti

I integrated activiti-explorer and OpenLDAP. After integrating activiti and LDAP, i am not able to deploy processes in activiti-explorer. How i can deploy a process after integration of activiti-explorer and OpenLDAP. Please help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some details about your problem? Does it look like an authorization issue or a runtime error ?

Comment: I integrated OpenLDAP and activiti-explorer. Login in activiti-explorer is successful. I am able to create a new process in activiti. When i click on deploy then deployment is also successful and it is automatically showing the deployments tab which is not showing before the deployment of process. The process is present in deployments. Now when i click on Processes tab then it is showing warning NULL in activiti-explorer and no error in Catalina.out . It is showing Warning NULL when i click on any tab i.e. Processes, Task, Database, etc.

Comment: I've seen this "warning null" before, but there were some kind of error message on the server side. Try to modify the log setting so you can see info/debug messages generated by activiti-explorer.

Comment: I want to ask you one more thing i.e. how to set the admin for the activiti after integrated with OpenLDAP who can upload new processes and delete the extra one.

Comment: There are no errors in catalina.out. when i deploy a process and click on processes then it is showing "warning Null" . If i got logout and again get login then its working fine. What is this behaviour. Can you give some suggestion.

Comment: It seems to me that that activi-explorer is caching something in the browser and/or server session. This would explay why thing work after a logout/login. As for the admin question: Did you follow the configuration steps described on section 17.5 of the activiti guide ? Admin users must map to a given group in your directory, which you should then associate with a given user.

Comment: BTW: I´m not a big fan of this kind of "deep" integration between LDAP and Activiti. If it suits your needs, by all means, use it ! However:  LDAP is something that is usually managed by IT guys, and any changes require a service desk call or something like that. BPM groups, in my experience, tend to be more fluid/dynamic, and, in order to scale its use, you need some kind of delegated group management, which is possible with LDAP but straightforward with activiti´s native groups. In fact, you can create a process just for that, with approvals and such.

Comment: ACT_ID_USER table is empty. It does not storing any user data but still i am able to login in activiti using OpenLDAP users. How i can store these users in ACT_ID_USER table from OpenLDAP.

Comment: Yes, i followed the configuration steps described in section 17.5. But administrator tab is not showing.

Comment: Try define the following system property: -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug=all . This should help to debug the with the group mapping issue.

Comment: As for users not being created: IFAIK this is the expected behaviour when you opt for LDAP integration: You´ll basically stop using those tables, so all users/group maitenance should be done through your LDAP admin interface (if you don´t have one, try JXplorer)

Comment: Because ACT_ID_USER table is empty. That's why I am not able to use REST in Activiti-explorer after integrate with OpenLDAP. I cant claim any task of any process using REST. Please give some solution, How to complete a task using REST in activiti-explorer when activiti-explorer is integrated with OpenLDAP.

Comment: It is showing some error in activiti-explorer when Warming:Null appear. It is something like this: com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method buttonClick in org.activiti.explorer.ui.mainlayout.MainMenuBar$ShowProcessDefinitionsClickListener failed.
 at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:530)

Comment: Did you change the security settings on the REST app ?  Their settings are independent of activiti-explorer´s, at least in the standard download package. If you want both to share the same settings you should move to properties files to a place that both webapps can "see" from their respective classloaders.

Comment: I am using activiti-5.14 downloaded from the http://activiti.org/download.html. I did not change any security setting on REST app. where to move the properties file so both the app can see these setting??

Comment: Sharing the configuration is a bit tricky if you´re not familiar with spring configuration files, but the general procedure is as follows: 1) Create a new spring  bean definition file that contains only the "processEngineConfiguration" bean that you´ve customized for LDAP; 2) Put the shared configuration in a place that both wars can "see". In Tomcat a suitable place is under $TOMCAT_HOME/conf ; 3)Remove the "processEngineConfiguration" bean from the spring config files in both wars and add an "import" directive that load the shared resource.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks for your help.. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help... Its working now.... :-)